# Which superheavy elements have color?

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, physical-chemistry

I read that gold is colorful because relativistic effects change electronic energy gaps ($5d$ to $6s$) so that some of them absorb photons in the visible range.

This effect is apparently due to higher charge in heavier nuclei, so we would expect it to be more pronounced in heavier elements, right?

So might we find colorful metals more common in the transition range below gold, elements 104 to 112 or so, where $d$ to $s$ transitions are also likely? Or is it different in the next row? Has there been any work predicting the spectral reflectance curves of these elements?

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16633/why-is-gold-golden

Comment: Without knowing the crystal structure (which gets really weird in the transuranics - see, e.g., plutonium's many allotropes) it makes any guesses at band structure almost impossible. Since it is band structure that determines the material's perceived color, well, this really isn't answerable.

Comment: @JonCuster The appearance of metals does not usually change much when they melt or have phase transitions. Yes, there are exceptions. like grey tin.

Comment: @Pieter - well, you did pick the one with a phase transition near room temperature so no pesky black body emission blinding you (with science!). As a non-metal counterpoint, I might point at carbon, where graphite and diamond are pretty different. Still, it doesn't take a big change in band structure (at the right places) to shift the color.

Answer (score 0):

Transition-row elements are grayish, slightly absorbing over the whole visible spectrum because of $dd$-transitions.

Gold is a noble metal, with a filled $d$ shell, like silver and copper. Copper is reddish, because blue light can be absorbed by exciting $3d$ electrons. In silver, the $4d$ bands are too deep below the Fermi level for that. In gold, relativistic spin-orbit interaction broadens (and splits) the $5d$ bands, so that some of these are in range again for blue light.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How does this relate to transuranic transition elements?

Comment: @MackTuesday The transuranics are transition metals, would be grayish if one could make enough material.